# Is it mandatory for Drools 7 to run in a separate JVM i.e. a KIE Server which holds the rules?

Tags: java, drools

Is it mandatory for Drools 7 to run in a separate JVM i.e. a KIE Server which holds the rules? Or we can continue to run Drools within the same JVM as the application?

We are migrating an application from older version of Drools where it is all in one JVM and wish to take a least resistance path for the version upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools 7 does not introduce any new restrictions compared to earlier versions of Drools. (I can only personally confirm back through Drools 5.0, however.) So while it does introduce many new capabilities, such as the KIE Server, it hasn't removed support for embedded/local rule execution as was traditionally supported in older versions.

If you refer to the [documentation](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#project-deployment-options-ref_decision-management-architecture), you can see that they explicitly indicate that you can deploy either to a KIE Server or to an embedded Java application and your own JVM environment.